# Open in explorer in other browsers?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, word, office-integration, explorer-view

We are using SP 2016 on-prem, and have an asset library with tons of pictures which users use by opening the asset library in "Explorer View". The problem is that it only works with IE and no other browser.

I am looking for workarounds to get the same kind of functionality as "Open in Explorer" on other browsers also. Any ideas how that can be achieved? Are there any workarounds for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Unfortunately,** it's one of the known limitation in Google Chrome!

> `Open with Explorer` **only** work with Internet Explorer.

[image]

**Ref:** [Copy or move library files by using Open with Explorer](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-or-move-library-files-by-using-Open-with-Explorer-aaee7bfb-e2a1-42ee-8fc0-bcc0754f04d2) (the last updated was in April 2017)

---

**Are there any workarounds for this?**

There is no frank workaround yet, But There is Google Extension called [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/related?hl=en) that allow you to open IE tab within Google Chrome **(Tried and Worked for 2013 /2016).**

[image]

Once the [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/related?hl=en) is added, open you sharepoint site > navigate to the library, click on [IE Tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ie-tab/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd/related?hl=en) extension,  now the current page in SharePoint Site will be shown in IE Tab within Google chrome as shown above, and the `Open with Explorer` option will be enabled!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, M.Qassas. Even Microsoft Edge don't support this functionality on their own products (yeah, I know it's because of Active X), and IE is now about to retire. They should provide us with a proper workaround/functionality here.

Comment: You're welcome @Ilyas :). I totally agree it's also not working in Edge. as I mentioned in my answer **Open with Explorer only work with Internet Explorer.** & *There is no frank workaround yet* !!!

Comment: I use the IE tab as well, but it can be a finnicky animal in Chrome sometimes.  When I'm in a hurry, I'll just give inn ad open IE 11 for this - it's the only supported browser to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You could map a windows drive to the library and have people access it from there. From a windows explorer window, use the 'Map Network Drive' 'Connect to a Web site that you can use to store your documents and pictures' option. Create a page that describes how to do that, or somehow push that out to others..

[image: Map Network Drive]

[image: Connect to Website]

**Make sure the WebClient service is running:**

​In Windows, go to Services and look for the WebClient. Make sure it is set to start automatically on reboot.

Workaround - start the service manually by using it. Open up an Explorer folder and navigate to \NAMEOFYOURSHAREPOINT@SSL\DavWWWRoot . That will start up the WebClient.

Comment: Are you referering to mapping by One Drive here ? Even One Drive cannot map\synchronize asset libraries. Or did you have something else in mind ? Got any samples\links ? :)

Comment: No, I meant in windows explorer - standard Tools.  I'll add a couple of pics to my answer. You have to make sure WebDav is set up to start automatically when you reboot - I'll have to go find that - I've got that documented somewhere else

Comment: Thanks Robin. Looking forward to see how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using MS Edge.
Check this article. With IE mode in Edge you will be able to use the Explorer function.
https://knowhowbank.tistory.com/188